# How do I use outreg2 to display value labels in its output?

Tags: stata

Take this code

```
sysuse auto, clear
reg price mpg c.mpg#i.foreign
outreg2 using "example.txt", stats(coef) replace
```

This outputs

```
    (1)
VARIABLES    price

price    
mpg    -329.0***
0b.foreign#co.mpg    0
1.foreign#c.mpg    78.33**
Constant    12,596***

Observations    74
R-squared    0.289
Standard errors in parentheses    
*** p<0.01, ** p<0.05, * p<0.1
```

Ideally, I'd like it to display the value labels, as is done in the console's regression output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          mpg |  -329.0368   61.46843    -5.35   0.000    -451.6014   -206.4723
              |
foreign#c.mpg |
     Foreign  |   78.32918   29.78726     2.63   0.010     18.93508    137.7233
              |
        _cons |   12595.97   1235.936    10.19   0.000     10131.58    15060.35
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't need any of the other stats at the moment; I'm strictly including that last piece of output to show what I mean with the value labels. Searching through the documentation for outreg2 tells me how to display *variable* labels, but not *value* labels.

Also [posted on Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1291059-how-do-i-use-outreg2-to-display-value-labels-in-its-output).

Comment: Have you considered switching to `estout`?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Does `estout` support doing this automatically? I've seen [Statalist posts](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-04/msg00960.html) that describe writing code to do this manually, but since `regress` already does this automatically, I'm hoping to find a solution that does the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dimitriy points out, you can use `estout`, from SSC. An example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

reg price mpg c.mpg#i.foreign

estimates store m1, title(Model 1)
estout m1, label
```

You can add other statistics, stars and more. After installation (`ssc install estout`), read patiently `help estout`.

Answer (score 0):

If you decode your variables and use `xi`, it will do the trick. Of course this solution assumes that you recode your variables, but if you want to stick with `outreg2` is an easy solution.

```
sysuse auto, clear
set seed 1234
gen maxspeed = round(uniform()*3)+1
label define speed 1 "Light" 2 "Ridiculous" 3 "Ludicrous" 4 "Plaid"
label values maxspeed speed
decode maxspeed, gen(maxspeed_str)
decode foreign, gen(foreign_str)
xi: reg price mpg weight i.foreign_str*i.maxspeed_str

outreg2 using test, see text label
```

I used the example you asked in Statalist as it was your latest question.